add objects of interest inside the map
I will be using intelresense 435d camera to find the location of the object and I want to update this object inside the map. Later i want to use this map to navigate near to that object.
I need your help in place where i want to put the object dynamically inside the map(dynamically means robot searchs for the object, when it finds it,then it places the object inside the map) and later using those object coordinates i should move closer to the object.
